# How to make sure the connection string is for a local machine

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string, sqlconnection

I'm creating a client application that connects to MS SQL Sever via ADO.NET. I need a user to specify a connection string to connect to a database. However users should only connect to SQL Server Express that is installed on their machine. I need to check the connection string to determine if it's a local one or not.

The obvious idea is to check whether the CS starts with "." or "local" or "*this_machine_name*". But I'm not sure that covers all possible cases.

Is there a better way to perform such a check?

UPD: I imply that there may be more than one instance of the SQL Server on the local machine, and instance names are not known. There also may be an unnamed instance.

UPD2: In fact I only ask users to specify an SQLServer instance.

Thank you.

Comment: you should also check 127.0.0.1 and in case of another IP, you should verify that such IP address is the same as Host IP address

Comment: I wouldn't let the user enter the complete connection string. Just let the user enter all relevant data *except* the host and add that yourself

Comment: What if the user wants to use the default unnamed SQL Server instance? Also, our goal is to use format similar to that MS SQL Management studio uses like "server\instance" or just "server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the connection string, extract the hostname from it, pass the hostname to System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String) and voíla! You get an IPHostEntry instance containing IP adresses. Check if 127.0.0.1 is there.

Comment: And if the CS contains no hostname (like "." or "(local)") we can just skip this check. Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than validating the connection string, would it not be easier to prompt the user for the database name, whether to use integrated auth or not and if not, the user name and password and then build your own connection string, using '(local)' as the server?

Comment: The thing is that there may be more than one instance of SQL Server on the machine, and instance names are not known.